# Diagonalization of a matrix by a basis

Tags: linear-algebra

> Corollary. Let $A$ be a complex unitary matrix. Then there exista a unitary matrix $U$ such that $U^{-1}AU$ is a diagonal matrix.

Proof. Let $\{e_1,...e_n\}=\mathscr{B}$ be the standard orthonormal baisis of $\mathbb{C}^2$, and let $\{w_1,...,w_n\}=\mathscr{B}´$ be an orthonormal basis which diagonalizes A, viewed as a linear map of $\mathbb{C}^n$ into itself. Let

$U=M^\mathscr{B´}_\mathscr{B}(id)$.

Then $U$ is unitary, and if $M´$ is the matrix of $A$ relative to the basis $\mathscr{B}´$, then

$M´=U^{-1}AU$.

It follows that $M´$ is unitary. ***Linear Algebra, Serge Lang***

**Question**:

Ihave been trying to understand this proof but I do not know how the author states "$\{w_1,...,w_n\}=\mathscr{B}´$ be an orthonormal basis which diagonalizes A". I have been investigating this issue but unsuccessfully I have not find clear examples of a diagonalization of a matrix by a basis. What does it mean?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since this result is a corollary, it is referring to the preceding theorem, which gives you exactly what you are looking for: there is an orthogonal basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$ consisting of eigenvalues of $A$, which is done by Gram-Schmidt.